# Adjective or Passive form?

Tags: grammar

I don't know if here is adjective or passive form

> They were the last people you'd expect **to be involved in** anything strange or 
>     mysterious, because they just didn't hold with such nonsense.

**Involved** has the role of adjective or passive form?

Comment: What makes you think it's an adjective?

Comment: What would the meaning be if it were a passive verb? What would the meaning be if it were an adjective?

Comment: It's an adjective, cf. "the last people to be **very involved** in anything strange ...". Only adjectives can be modified by "very".

Comment: @BillJ
There is no "very" word in my sentence.

Comment: @user178049 **involve** is a verb and we can add "ed" to turn it into adjective. => involved

Comment: I realise that. My example was intended to show that the adverb "very" can be inserted as a modifier of "involved", thus proving that "involved" is an adjective, not a verb, since the latter cannot be modified by "very".

Comment: @ BillJ . I have a similar example .,**This is a house you'd expect to be built** . so, **built** in this case is passive verb or adjective?

Comment: @ Peter Shor. I think about that problem,too. I can't translate it if I don't know what kind of word it is

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going on this. You asked if "involved" was an adjective or a verb (i.e. participle) in your example, and got the answer that it's an adjective. Your new example makes little sense, but "built" is a verb, and hence it's a passive clause. In the case of "involved" there is no possibility of inserting a _by_ phrase which also indicates that it's an adjective.

Comment: involved is also a verb?

Comment: There is a verb "involve", whose past tense form is "involved". But it's not a verb in your example; it's an adjective functioning as a predicative complement of "be". The adjective form is of course derived from the verb.

Comment: @BillJ: You can also add "closely": "the last people to be **closely involved** in anything strange ...". Only verbs can be modified by "closely".

Comment: This may help: [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/involved)

Comment: @Pham Van Duc: When you translate something, you can't always keep the parts of speech the same. For example, look up the adjective *welcome* in the Larousse English-French dictionary. They translate "you're welcome to anything you need" to "servez-vous si vous avez besoin de quelque chose", which is literally "help yourself if you have need of some thing." *Welcome* is an adjective, but the translation has no adjectives except for *quelque* in *quelque chose* (meaning *some thing.*) That's because there is no adjective meaning *welcome* in French.

Comment: @PeterShor It is not true that "closely" can only modify verbs. For example, it can modify "indebted" which is an uncontroversial adjective. "Involved" is an adjective in the OP's example, as the "very" test demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

Most "be + V-ed" phrases can work, depending on the context, as passive forms or as copulative verb + adjective. Such structures will be interpreted as passive if reference is made to the **action**, and as adjectival if reference is made to the **state**.

In the sentence at issue, the adverbial clause of reason makes it clear that "be involved" is a state, so "involved" is adjectival -- they were not keen on strange or mysterious things, so they could not possibly be involved or implicated in any such things.

If that adverbial were not there, the sentence would be ambiguous, and the passive meaning would be possible:

- They were the last people you'd expect to be involved (by anybody) in anything strange or mysterious. (This could be the case if everyone believed they were honest, reasonable people, in which case it was unlikely for them to be accused by others of being involved in or associated with anything strange or mysterious).

Comment: So,at that position, I can use a adjective or verb, right?

Comment: In that sentence, with an adverbial of reason that describes what they were like, "involved" is adjectival as it refers to the state or condition of (not) being implicated in strange or mysterious things

Comment: Ok. I have a similar example .,**This is a house you'd expect to be built** . so, **built** in this case is passive verb or adjective?

Comment: I need you to complete the sentence. As it is, it can be passive or adjectival. Some further context could help us define which it is.